# wp category showing all posts from all categories instead of specific posts from specific category

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I'm building a site on wp and can't seem to get over this obstacle, when I go to a specific category archive page, it shows all the posts from all the categories instead of just the ones in that category... Wondering if anyone has can help me figure out how to limit the results to show just the posts from the category called.

Here's my category.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span10">
            <div class="gridContainer">

                <?php
                    $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'orderby' => 'date',
                    'order' => 'DESC',
                    'posts_per_page' => 999)); // how many posts to show
                     $x = 0;

                 while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
                 $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="view view-tenth"> 
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('grid-image'); ?> 
                        <div class="mask"> 
                            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2> 
                            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p> 
                             <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="info">Take Me To The Porn!</a> 
                        </div> <!-- mask -->
                </div> <!-- view view-tenth -->

                    <?php $x++; ?>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>

                    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
                    <div class="clear"></div>

            </div> <!-- gridContainer -->

        </div> <!-- span10 -->

        <div class="span2">
            <?php get_template_part('sidebar'); ?>
        </div> <!-- span2 -->
    </div> <!-- row -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are creating your own WP_Query you have to precise the actual filter you are using. For categories look at the relevant documentation here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters

Note that if you are modifying the category.php template you are already inside the wordpress Loop and you do not need to specify your own WP_Query. You can simply use a

```
while(have_posts() ):
    ...
endwhile;
```

loop. I would recommend downloading the [TwentyTwelve](http://wordpress.org/themes/twentytwelve) theme and observing its inner workings.